# What is the best way to get differences from unique rows of two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

For example, we have two dataframes from two weeks of competitions:

**Week 1 Stats:**

| Rank | Player | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff | 4 |
| 2 | Jose | 3 |
| 3 | John | 2 |
| 4 | Joel | 1 |

**Week 2 Stats:**

| Rank | Player | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jose | 4 |
| 2 | Joel | 3 |
| 3 | Jeff | 2 |
| 4 | John | 1 |

I want to create a third dataframe that returns the player-specific differences, so something like `df_differences = Week1['Jose'].subtract(Week2['Jose'])` but on a much larger scale with 500+ players.

I thought of assigning a unique player ID to each player and then the function would just need to look for player ID and return respective differences. But even still I'm not quite sure how that would look. Thanks everyone!

### df1

EDIT: CSV snippet

```
,Player,% Owned,+/-,GP,mask1,mask2
0,Player1,3%,0%,0,False,False
1,Player2,91%,0%,1,False,False
2,Player3,99%,0%,1,False,False
3,Player4,57%,-0.1%,1,False,False
```

### df2

```
,Player,% Owned,+/-,GP,mask1,mask2
0,Player1,3%,0%,0,False,False
1,Player2,91%,0%,1,False,False
2,Player3,99%,0%,1,False,False
3,Player4,57%,-0.1%,1,False,False
4,Adam 0%,0%,0,False,False
5,Adam,20%,0%,1,False,False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the players as index:

```
Week1.set_index('Player') - Week2.set_index('Player')
```

Or:

```
Week1.set_index('Player').sub(Week2.set_index('Player'))
```

Comment: With that change I'm now running into an `operand type(s)` error. What I was doing before was I was removing non-integers with `Week1 = Week1.select_dtypes(['number'])` then get differences with `.sub()`, and **then** I would `.pop('Player')` and `.join('Player')`.

Any ideas?